# Overriding model attribute readers does not affect simple_form input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using simple_form and want to override readers for model attributes.

Thus following does not work

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base

  # it has attribute named pack

  def pack
    "Some value"
  end

end
```

In view there is following code

```
<%= simple_form_for @c do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :pack %>
<% end %>
```

thus it should show form with input box having value "Some value" but it is blank. Why doesn't override work with simple_form?

Comment: I have the same problem, my guess is `simple_form`, or more likely rails form helpers, use `read_attribute` instead of `send` to get the input values from ActiveRecord objects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured this out, my comment was basically correct, `simple_form` leans on Rails form helpers which use `read_attribute` to get the value from an ActiveRecord object thus reading the value in the database and not using your method. A symptom of coupling persistence/domain/presentation. The way around this is:

```
 <%= f.input :pack, :input_html => { :value => @c.pack } %>
 # or
 <%= f.input :pack, :input_html => { :value => f.object.pack } %>
```

Or if you want this to be default behaviour you can create your own form builder on top of `simple_for` such as:

```
# lib/my_form_builder.rb **

class MyFormBuilder < SimpleForm::FormBuilder                                                                                               
  def input(attribute_name, options={}, &block)                                 
    options[:input_html] ||= {}                                                 
    options[:input_html][:value] = object.send(attribute_name)                  
    super(attribute_name, options, &block)                                                          
  end
end
```

And in your form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @c, :builder => MyFormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :pack %>
<% end %>
```

** in Rails 3 I don't think `lib` is added to the load path by default so you might need to add it and restart you app *or* put it in `app/models` (disclaimer not a good idea, lib is better).

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 3.2 at least, it isn't using read_attribute directly anymore. But if you're using a text field, it uses [InstanceTag.value_before_type_cast](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/488699166c3558963fa82d4689a35f8c3fd93f47/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1155) to retrive the value. This uses:

```
object.respond_to?(method_name + "_before_type_cast") ?
  object.send(method_name + "_before_type_cast") :
  object.send(method_name)
```

(where method_name is the attribute name in that context)

So if you'd like to make sure that the form uses your attribute accessor, add the following alias:

```
  alias pack_before_type_cast pack
```

That works for me, just make sure to return a string there...

Comment: Worked for me. Had to use `alias_method` cuz i was in a concern